# How do I incorporate a loopback application with cordova?

Tags: cordova, strongloop

I have a front end that I've made with Cordova and I would to integrate it with a loopback REST API using the Angular SDK.

Any updated examples?

Answer (score 1):

Here are a few good examples:

https://github.com/strongloop/icars-client (LoopBack+PhoneGap)

https://github.com/strongloop/loopback-example-access-control (Ionic+AngularJS+LoopBack)

StrongLoop has its own example implementation, BACN: https://strongloop.com/strongblog/bacn-scrabble-alternatives-to-bootstrap-angular-cordova-and-node/

Comment: These examples don't actually connect to the REST api.  There's an issue about it right now.